# Django error con filter con 10 números

Tags: python, django, django-models

La siguiente funciona debe seleccionar 10 preguntas:

```
def pregunta(request):

    #este selecciona un pack de 10 números de pregunta
    respuestas = Respuesta.objects.filter(idUsuario=281,modalidadPreguntas='operarioDeServicios',respuestasCorrectas__lt=4)[:10]

    #este selecciona todas (all) pero debería filtrar sólo los 10 números que ha recopilado respuestas:
    preguntas = Pregunta.objects.filter(modalidadPregunta='operarioDeServicios')
```

¿Cómo hago para que preguntas filtre según números que ha recopilados respuestas?

Ejemplo:

respuestas = [1,3,4,5,7,8,9,11,14,16]

Que preguntas no tenga all(), sino 10 preguntas cuyo número de pregunta sea los indicados en la tupla o array respuestas.

No se si me he explicado bien.

**Clase de la tabla Respuestas:**

(Aquí se recopilan todos los resultados de los usuarios. Es aquí donde hay que tomar los 10 números de pregunta < 4 (respuestasCorrecta) para luego seleccionar en la tabla preguntas según esos 10 números.

```
class Respuesta(models.Model):
    idUsuario = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True, blank=True)
    modalidadPreguntas = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True, blank=True)
    numeroPregunta = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
    respuestasCorrectas = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True)
```

**Clase de la tabla Preguntas:**

```
class Pregunta(models.Model):
    preguntaTest = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    modalidadPregunta = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)
    numeroPregunta = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
```

**Consulta en tabla Respuestas de 10 números de pregunta cuyo respuestaCorrecta sea inferior a 4. Y con esa tupla de 10 números de pregunta, en la tabla Preguntas tomar tupla de 10 pregunta según esos 10 números:**

```
ids_respuestas = []
for respuesta in respuestas.values(): 
    ids_respuestas.append(respuesta.get("numeroPregunta"))
preguntas = Pregunta.objects.filter(modalidadPregunta='operarioDeServicios', numeroPregunta__in=ids_respuestas)
return render(request, "pregunta/pregunta.html",{'preguntas':preguntas,'respuestas':respuestas})
```

Un saludo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar el `__in` para buscar multiples elementos.

Si no me equivoco esto debería funcionarte.

```
ids_respuestas = []
for respuesta in respuestas.values():
    ids_respuestas.append(respuesta.get("id"))
preguntas = Pregunta.objects.filter(modalidadPregunta='operarioDeServicios', respuestas__in=ids_respuestas)
```

Espero te sea útil.

Comment: Pero en este caso sabes los números, los insertas los del ejemplo y ya, pero los crea "respuestas", ¿puedo hacer así como: respuestas__in=respuesta[0],respuesta[1],respuesta[2],respuesta[3],respuesta[4],respuesta[5],respuesta[6],respuesta[7],respuesta[8],respuesta[9], ?¿Se puede?

Comment: Podrías, pero te recomiendo crear una tupla con las respuestas y pasarla, edito mi respuesta resolviendo tu pregúnta..

Comment: te lo agradezco!

Comment: Listo, verifica si funciona. no estoy totalmente seguro, pero esa sería la logica del codigo

Comment: Tiene todo el sentido y te lo agradezco, pero algo tengo mal:

Comment: ids_respuestas = [Pregunta.objects.filter(modalidadPregunta='operarioDeServicios')]
    for respuesta in respuestas.values():
    ids_respuestas.append(respuesta.get("numeroPregunta"))
    preguntas = Pregunta.objects.filter(modalidadPregunta='operarioDeServicios', numeroPregunta__in=ids_respuestas)
    return render(request, "pregunta/pregunta.html",{'preguntas':preguntas,'respuestas':respuestas})

Comment: No logro entender el último comentario, edita tu pregunta y coloca ese código.

Comment: Ok! He completado la pregunta, con tu propuesta y añadiendo las tablas. Gracias.

Comment: Lo veo, pero indícame cuál es el problema, no te muestra los valores en el html? Has intentado depurar o hacer un print a tus valores?

Comment: funciona perfecto! Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Al final funcionó de la siguiente manera:
**respuesta** toma la consulta en forma de tupla, que después se lo pasamos a **preguntas**. Hacemos return de preguntas y lo mostramos en la página mediante for.

```
respuestas = Respuesta.objects.filter(idUsuario=290,modalidadPreguntas='operarioDeServicios',respuestasCorrectas__lt=4).values_list('numeroPregunta', flat=True)[:10]
    preguntas = Pregunta.objects.filter(modalidadPregunta='operarioDeServicios', numeroPregunta__in=respuestas)
    return render(request, "pregunta/pregunta.html",{'preguntas':preguntas})
```